# Missing Shell Menu Entries For .dll Files

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Recently, I adjusted the default program that .dll's open in when double-clicked on my system. However, doing so seems to have killed the right-click menus custom extension entries now and I can no longer access tools quickly via right-click and selecting a program option.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

The top part of the menu used to have several other entries including:

- Open with CFF Explorer
- Open with OllyDbg
- Scan with PEiD
- UniExtract Files...
- UniExtract Here
- UniExtract to Subdir

and some others. Looking into the registry and using shell menu editors, the entries all still exist for these but Windows refuses to display them.

Is there some way to restore these menu entries?

Comment: "I adjusted the default program that .dll's open in when double-clicked on my system", this was probably a bad idea. If you put it back the way it was, does it go back to working as expected?

Comment: Altering what it opens with by default on double-clicking doesn't harm the system or make DLLs not work. Just changes what they open with when you double-click them in explorer etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable/disable them using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). You may also do a registry scan:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately toggling their status didn't help. However I did find a utility that did work to fix the problem. http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/unassociate-file-types-windows-7-vista/ Removing the user defined association to the file fixed it.